# How to temporary block clients, which produce bad requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Within our REST api server we'd like to introduce same rate limit for bad acting clients. E.g. a client sends multiple request per second/minute/whatever which produces results with status code 4xx, the corresponding client will be blocked for 1 minute/hour/whatever.

After a little search I found some projects like [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit), but they all seem to only count incoming requests and after a little reading the code, here is the *heart* of the implementation that counts the requests:

```
public class IpRateLimitMiddleware
{
    // ... some private fields and a ctor that takes some dependencies

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // ... some extraction of values like remote ip, route, etc.
        // ... some checks if any defined rule matches
        // ... if rule found, check counter
        if(counter >= rule.counter)
        {
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(blockedMessage);
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}
```

But all these rules only affect incoming requests **before** they are handled. But I like to check the result **after** they are handled to increase the counter. Is their anything out there, that already covers this scenario? And if not, how can I know the result status code in my middleware to increase the rule counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to evaluate it after, change your middleware code to run *after* the call to `_next`.